# Area of Lists of Lists

Tags: python, area

Been trying to figure out how to complete this operation with no avail

> Each item in this list is a pair of numbers that represent the dimensions of rooms in a house:

```
h = [ [18,12], [14,11], [8,10], [8,10] ]
```

> Write a function named area that computes the total area of all rooms, for example:

```
> area(h)
530
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def area(h):
  total_area = 0
  for room in h:
    total_area += room[0] * room[1]
  return total_area
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: This is furthermore not considered very pythonic.

Comment: What I mean is that something as simple as: `area = lambda x: sum(w*l for w,l in x)` would do